# Issue Joining SQL table with statement containing Row Number Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, excel, join

Using SQL in excel, I have created a statement to pull and join records using the following post as a guide 
[SQL 2008 Combining data from multiple rows with the same ID into one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802001/sql-2008-combining-data-from-multiple-rows-with-the-same-id-into-one-row) (First Answer)
I am not able to figure out how to join an additional table to it now. I think I am just adding it to the wrong area.

Here is the working code:

```
sql = sql & "select REPID, ReportDate, "
sql = sql & "max(case when CategoryID = 5001 then Score end) InPercent, "
sql = sql & "max(case when CategoryID = 5002 then Score end) OutPercent "
sql = sql & "from "
sql = sql & "(select REPID, ReportDate, Score, CategoryID, row_number() over(partition by REPID, ReportDate order by Score) rn from REPREPORTING RR Where RepID <> 0) "
sql = sql & " d group by REPID, ReportDate "
```

And here is the join statement I need to add:

```
sql = sql & "JOIN EMPCUR_EmployeeCurr P ON P.employee_token_nr = RR.REPID "
```

I normally would put this at the end of the statement, and have tried that and get the error Incorrect syntax near the word join. I have also placed it prior to the group by line with the same error.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: RR refers to a table inside the subquery. If you want to join outside of the subquery, refer to `d.REPID` instead (subquery is `d`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
with d as (
  select RR.REPID, RR.ReportDate, RR.Score, RR.CategoryID,
  row_number() over(partition by RR.REPID, RR.ReportDate order by RR.Score) rn
  from REPREPORTING RR
  JOIN EMPCUR_EmployeeCurr P ON P.employee_token_nr = RR.REPID  -- right here
  Where RR.RepID <> 0
)
select
  d.REPID, d.ReportDate,
  max(case when d.CategoryID = 5001 then d.Score end) InPercent,
  max(case when d.CategoryID = 5002 then d.Score end) OutPercent
from
  d
group by
  d.REPID, d.ReportDate
```

I moved your subquery `d` into a CTE for readability, so don't read too much into that.

You *could* move the join to the outer query (d), but it's more efficient to eliminate rows before invoking grouping function -- the fewer rows you need to group, the better your query will run.

That said, once I did this I couldn't help but notice that your `rn` field, which invokes a windowing function, doesn't appear to have any impact.  Did you mean to use this, perhaps to take only the first row:

```
with d as (
  select RR.REPID, RR.ReportDate, RR.Score, RR.CategoryID,
  row_number() over(partition by RR.REPID, RR.ReportDate order by RR.Score) rn
  from REPREPORTING RR
  JOIN EMPCUR_EmployeeCurr P ON P.employee_token_nr = RR.REPID
  Where RR.RepID <> 0
)
select
  d.REPID, d.ReportDate,
  max(case when d.CategoryID = 5001 then d.Score end) InPercent,
  max(case when d.CategoryID = 5002 then d.Score end) OutPercent
from
  d
where
  d.rn = 1    --  Did you mean to add this?
group by
  d.REPID, d.ReportDate
```

If not, I think you can completely avoid the CTE/subquery altogether and eliminate the windowing function (`row_number`), which while one of my favorite functions, does have some cost associated with it:

```
select
  RR.REPID, RR.ReportDate,
  max(case when RR.CategoryID = 5001 then RR.Score end) InPercent,
  max(case when RR.CategoryID = 5002 then RR.Score end) OutPercent
from
  from REPREPORTING RR
  JOIN EMPCUR_EmployeeCurr P ON P.employee_token_nr = RR.REPID
group by
  RR.REPID, RR.ReportDate
```

And, of course, the VBA version:

```
sql = _
  "select " & _
  "  RR.REPID, RR.ReportDate, " & _
  "  max(case when RR.CategoryID = 5001 then RR.Score end) InPercent, " & _
  "  max(case when RR.CategoryID = 5002 then RR.Score end) OutPercent " & _
  "from " & _
  "  from REPREPORTING RR " & _
  "  JOIN EMPCUR_EmployeeCurr P ON P.employee_token_nr = RR.REPID " & _
  "group by " & _
  "  RR.REPID, RR.ReportDate"
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cant** put the `JOIN` at the end.

Right now you have:

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM <subquery>
GROUP BY <fields>
```

You either want join with the subquery

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM <subquery> s
JOIN <anotherTable> t ON  s.joinCondition = t.joinCondition
GROUP BY <fields>
```

Or `JOIN` inside the subquery

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM <subquery JOIN here> s
GROUP BY <fields>
```